# How to show/hide div content with nested ul list

Tags: jquery, show-hide, nested-lists

I have a nested ul list with links that serve as the navigation to show/hide hidden divs on the same page.  The nesting works similar to an accordion.

The hidden divs have an id that is the same as the href of it's corresponding nav link.  I can show/hide dives with the li's that don't have children, but I can't figure out how to make this also work for li's with children.

Here is my html:

```
// Nav
<nav class="mtpd-manual-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#chiefs-preface" class="active">Chief's Preface</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#law-enforcement-code-of-ethics">Law Enforecement Code of Ethics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mission-statement-and-core-values">Mission Statement and Core Values</a></li>
        <li>Law Enforcement Role and Authority
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#100-law-enforcement-authority">100 - Law 
Enforcement Authority</a></li>
                <li><a href="#102-chief-executive-officer">102 - Chief 
Executive Officer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#104-oath-of-office">104 - Oath of Office</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#106-policy-manual">106 - Policy Manual</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

// Div content
<div id="chiefs-preface" style="display: block;">
    <h2>Chief's Preface</h2>
    <p>Div 1 content...</p>
</div>
<div id="law-enforcement-code-of-ethics">
    <h2>Law Enforcement Code of Ethics</h2>
    <p>Div 2 content...</p>
</div>
<div id="mission-statement-and-core-values">
    <h2>Mission Statement and Core Values</h2>
    <p>Div 3 content</p>
</div>
<div id="law-enforcement-role-and-authority">
    <h2>Law Enforcement Role and Authority</h2>
    <div id="100-law-enforcement-authority">
        <h3>100 - Law Enforcement Authority</h3>
        <p>Div 4 content...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="102-chief-executive-officer">
        <h3>102 - Chief Executive Officer</h3>
        <p>Div 5 content...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
// Expand Collapse list
$('.mtpd-manual-menu li').click(function(e){
    if( $(this).find('>ul').hasClass('active') ){
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url("/Data/Sites/1/skins/MetroTransitII/images/PlusSmall.gif")').children('ul').removeClass('active').slideUp();
    e.stopPropagation();
    }
    else{
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url("/Data/Sites/1/skins/MetroTransitII/images/MinusSmall.gif")').children('ul').addClass('active').slideDown();
    e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

// Show content based on link clicked.
$('.mtpd-manual-menu a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.left-col div').hide();
    $('.mtpd-manual-menu li a').removeClass('active'); // remove any existing 'active' classes.
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add class to currently active link.
    var id = $(this).attr('href'); // Get href of active link.
    $(id).show(); // Show div with matching id of active link href.
});
```

Comment: I think your HTML code is incomplete.

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I see my HTML is incomplete.  Also, looking at the requirements again I added an unnecessary nested div.

Answer (score 0):

So while my HTML was incomplete, I also noticed I don't need the nested divs.  So removing the parent div solves my issue.